# Is there a C# mathematics framework that can do numerical indefinite integration?

Tags: c#, math, frameworks, numerical-integration

I need to calculate the indefinite integral (or antiderivative) of a function in C#, but most frameworks I've come across only support definite integration. I've had a look at Math.NET, ILNumerics.NET and some others, but didn't find what I was looking for.

To be clear, I need numerical integration, not something like a parser which evaluates expressions or equations analytically. I need something like:

```
Func<double, double> IntegrateIndefinitely(Func<double, double> function, Point constraint);
```

It doesn't matter how functions are represented, could as well be a custom type or arrays of double or whatever.

I know that I could extend the above frameworks to return a function which represents the indefinite integral, but I would prefer something tested in terms of performance and correctness.

**Do you know a math framework which can calculate the indefinite integral of a function in C#?**

Comment: Since indefinite integral is known up to the arbitrary constant: IndefiniteIntegral(f(x)) = F(x) + C;
you can try using definite integral, because DefiniteIntegral(f(x), x, a) = F(x) - F(a) = F(x) + C

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: As you can see in the function signature, I would like to be able to set a constraint, so that C can be resolved. I know that I could get the function I need by evaluating the definite integral in sufficiently small increments over my function, but that is not efficient obviously.

Comment: @Adriano: I know, that's why I don't ask 'in your opinion which library should I use to get' but 'is there a library which can do ...'. What's wrong about that???

Comment: @Marc Questions about "what's the library to do this" are off topic (cite: "Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it").

Comment: @Adriano: I don't want a recommendation, I want to know whether there are libraries capable of doing indefinite integration. That's a clear question, I've presented code to explain how the interface I am searching for should look like. How can an answer to this question be opinionated??? Stuff like this is so annoying, just a waste of time.

Comment: @Marc I strongly agree it's a waste of time. SO is for **questions related to [programming problems](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)** not a search engine or a discussion board. Sorry for that but each SE site has its own (narrow) topic to help community to search (and find) the right answer (that's the point of "...questions asking us **to recommend** a tool, **library**...are **off topic**..."). It doesn't mean you may not find an answer but this would encourage someone else to ask "I have to do this, which language should I use?"...

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral is a family of functions, "F(x)+C", where F is any particular solution. Given a procedure for calculating a definite integral of `f` in any interval, you can pick F(x) as the definite integral from any abscissa to x.

Given a way to calculate the definite integral of `f` in an interval, the indefinite integral function `F` that passes through the `constraint` point (u,v) is:

```
F(x) = definite_integral(f, u, x) + v;
```

On the other hand, if you want to avoid recalculating the integral for every point what you are actually looking for is a routine for solving the ordinary differential equation `F'(x) = f(x)` with the given constraint. Any decent library of numerical analysis should have several functions for solving ODEs.

Comment: As you can see in the function signature, I would like to be able to set a constraint, so that C can be resolved. I know that I could get the function I need by evaluating the definite integral in sufficiently small increments over my function, but that is not efficient obviously. I don't need one particular value of the indefinite integral but the complete function in aform that I can integrate again or just plot it.

Comment: Ah, I glossed over the constraint point. That makes the solution easier; see update.

Comment: That's a very good point to regard the problem as differential equation. I'll have a look at the libraries again with this in mind and get back to you. Thanks!